# How to check if device is Windows Surface Tablet and browser is chrome or IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to check if device is Windows Surface Tablet and browser is chrome or IE using Javascript.
i have tried following code

```
function is_touch_device() 
{  
  try {  
    document.createEvent("TouchEvent");  
    return true;  
  } catch (e) {  
    return false;  
  }  
}
if(is_touch_device() )
{
    if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome')>-1)
     {
       //some stuff
      }
}
```

i have searched for useragent
but i an not getting exact for surface.
 how to check if device is surface and browser is chrome or IE

Comment: What have you tried? What have you researched so far?  People aren't going to just simply do your work for you.  Put in a little effort first.

Comment: Surface is a touch device maybe with a mouse maybe with a real keyboard with whatever browser the user installed and launched (I use Fx). There are tons of *hybrid* PCs (desktops and laptops with a touch screen) where Touch Events will probably return true but it isn't a Surface. I fail to see the need of UA string detection when Modernizr and such have better mechanisms of detection

Answer (score 2):

Using the navigator object you can access these data fields

```
navigator.appName  <- gets app name may be misleading so also get the appCodeName
navigator.appCodeName; <-- alternate name
navigator.platform; <-- platform the user is on
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_navigator.asp

Comment: In what way? Did you even try my answer?

Comment: What was wrong with the code? When I use it, it works. Unless you tell me what error you are going or show me what you are trying its hard for me to help you. Please be more descriptive than "post proper code".

Answer (score 2):

```
window.navigator.pointerEnabled
```

This method returned true Surface devices.....

Comment: window.navigator.pointerEnabled returns undefined on a Microsoft Surface Go 2 (Chrome Broswer), can you explain why that is so? Isn't this Surface a "true Surface Device"?

Answer (score 1):

Though you can use navigator object to serve your purpose, I would suggest you to use modernizer for the same.