# OS scaling CSS media query

Tags: css, media-queries, scale

Client has the following display settings on Windows Surface. He is seeing a website quite differently that to what I am seeing. What CSS media query can I use to be able to make adjustments to allow for these specific settings

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would start with:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 2736px) and (min-height: 1824px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    ...
}
```

You can also detect it via JS.
Read this: [How to check if device is Windows Surface Tablet and browser is chrome or IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29091862/how-to-check-if-device-is-windows-surface-tablet-and-browser-is-chrome-or-ie/45547733)

And if it's a Surface, add some CSS class dynamically to the appropiate elements.